# Escaping SQL “ILIKE” usando a bilbioteca psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

Eu segui essa [topico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106207/escape-sql-like-value-for-postgres-with-psycopg2) aqui no stack para tentar criar um select no qual eu procuro por uma pessoa usando a função ILIKE, porém eu tenho o retorno de "None", mesmo fazendo alterações na coluna e tabela para ver se me gera um erro diferente, o retorno é o mesmo "None"

```
def searchPeople(name):
    try:
        conn = Connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')
        name= name.replace('=', '==').replace('%', '=%').replace('_', '=_')
        result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ilike %(like)s",dict(like='%'+ name+'%'))
        print result
        cur.close()
    except Exception as e:
        return e
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Erro de sintaxe na expressão SQL, corrija para: `SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ilike '%(like)s'`. Mas você efetivamente quer as linhas onde o campo `name` contenha a string `'(like)s'`?

Comment: Me desculpa, na hora de passar para o fórum eu escrevi junto `nameilike` . Estou fazendo um formulário autocomplete e vou passar essa função para a view, nesse caso o usuário começará a escrever uma letra e o restante vai aparecer, essa string `%(like)s` foi a maneira que eu encontrei de fazer o escape, depois eu substituo ela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o operador de concatenação de strings `||`:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ilike '%%' || %s || '%%'; ", (name,))
```

Usando a função de concatenação de strings `CONCAT()`:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ilike CONCAT('%%', %s, '%%'); ", (name,))
```